# What is the name of the NLP technique that determines "who did what to whom" given a sentence?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, computational-linguistics

Within a piece of text, I'm trying to detect who did what to whom.

For instance, in the following sentences:

> CV hit IV. CV was hit by IV.

I'd like to know who hit whom.

I can't remember what this technique is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be referring to [**Semantic role labeling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_role_labeling). SRL is the task of assigning labels to words or phrases in a sentence that shows their semantic role in that sentence.

In your example `CV was hit by IV`, the task is to identify the verb "hit" carried out by the `actor` "CV" affected "IV" the `recipient`.

Note: If you're only interested in the syntactic relationship among words or phrases in a sentence, not the semantic relationship between them, simple **dependency parsing** would do the job.